# Before and After Hover Effect

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have been scouring the web on before and after effects and I just haven't.. found anything remotely helpful. It's like the gray area of CSS. I was wondering how I would go about doing an effect like on twitter's homepage: This is on the hover effect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJm16.jpg. It has a transition too, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Again i'm not even sure if this is using before and after, I imagine it is hover, but any help would be really appreciated.

Here is my code for my navigation:

```
<div id="navbar3" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

Comment: its done with javascript not css

Comment: @magreenberg if OP is talking about the animate underline, then it's done with CSS.

Comment: @magreenberg its done with css, not javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `:after` and `:before` [pseudo selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/). 
Im created an example based on your image, its look like this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body{
  padding: 5%;
}

.exemple {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2.5% 3.5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #333333;
  transition: ease .1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease .1s;
}

.exemple:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f0e7';
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.exemple:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background: #20abe1;
  transition: ease .1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease .1s;
}

.exemple:hover {
  color: #20abe1;
}

.exemple:hover:after{
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="exemple">Moments</a>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/348ch30g/)

Comment: Thank you. As much as I appreciate this answer, I still have absolutely no idea how to it myself

Comment: Run and read line by line, read about :before and :after and try to do it by yourself. If you have a specific question you can write it here as a comment.

Comment: do  transition: ease .1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease .1s; have to be on before and after?? if so why

Comment: Its necessary because you make the :hover changes on :after and :before selector. If we drop the transition from them its just change it without any ease. Its clearly?

Comment: @EllisJohnston `:before` and `:after` create pseudo elements. Elements that are inserted before and/or after the specified element. You treat them like any other element. If you needed to animate a DIV's `height` you would need to use `transition` on that DIV. You have to do the same for pseudo elements.

Comment: Pseudo-elements should have double colons (`::before` and `::after`).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a `::before` or you can animate the border/padding and it will create the same grow effect. Working fiddle here: [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cLn25L8j/)

Comment: Please make sure you include any relevant code in the answer itself. If/when JSFiddle goes down, this answer becomes largely useless.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a much detail on the exact thing you're attempting to replicate. I'm going to assume it's the underline that animates up from the bottom of a navigation item.

To do this you will need to use CSS transition.

A simplified version of what Twitter is doing is below. They set a height on the `<a>` and `<li>` and add a border to the `<a>`. Since they have `overflow:hidden;` applied to the border of the `<li>` the border they applied to the `<a>` is initially hidden.

When the `<li>` is hovered the height of the `<a>` is reduced. They use transition on the height to animate the border up into view.

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0c0;
  transition: height 250ms ease-in-out;
}
li:hover a {
  height: 37px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is another way of animating in the underline with pseudo elements.

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0c0;
  transition: height 250ms ease-in-out;
}
li:hover a:after {
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: More than one way to skin this cat.